# Bootstrap 4 - Multi row cards are not responsive correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my cards row responsive with some margin but when I apply `margin:5px;` to my cards, the row overflows. They are not aligned at the center correctly. There is some space left on the right side of the cards. How can I make them aligned at the center properly?

Here is my HTML and CSS:
http://codepen.io/reklamarsiv/pen/vgPLLv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the padding and margin inside of the `col-*` tags. Create a `div` inside with the class of card instead of putting the class of card in the same `div`.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card">
        // contents of card...
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjRpQd